# Pandas dataframe check if a value exists in multiple columns for one row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to print out the row where the value is "True" for more than one column.

For example if data frame is the following:

```
   Remove  Ignore  Repair
0    True   False   False
1   False    True    True
2   False    True   False
```

I want it to print:

```
1
```

Is there an elegant way to do this instead of bunch of if statements?

Comment: `df[df.sum(1).gt(1)].index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first row that meets the criteria:

`df.index[df.sum(axis=1).gt(1)][0]`

Output:

`Out[14]: 1`

Since you can get multiple matches, you can exclude the `[0]` to get all the rows that meet your criteria

Answer (score 2):

- you can use sum and pass axis=1 to sum over columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[False, True, False],'b':[False, True, False], 'c':[True, False, False,]})
print(df)
print("Ans: ",df[(df.sum(axis=1)>1)].index.tolist())
```

output:

```
      a       b      c
0   False   False   True
1   True    True    False
2   False   False   False
Ans: [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just sum booleans as they will be interpreted as True=1, False=0:

`df.sum(axis=1) > 1`

So to filter to rows where this evaluates as True:

`df.loc[df.sum(axis=1) > 1]`

Or the same thing but being more explicit about converting the booleans to integers:

`df.loc[df.astype(int).sum(axis=1) > 1]`